# Cron Job Issue with day of Month

Tags: cron

I have a cron job set to run a script once a day at 3am.

```
0 3 * * * /home/path/script.pl
```

It's been running without any problems since April 11th. Last weekend though, on Saturday the 3rd of May, the script was called once a minute for 24 hours. (1441 times in total) Then afterwards, on the 4th and 5th, it went back to only being called once a day at 3:00 again.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this happened? I was wondering if there was an error in my crontab, since I have a 3 in it, and it was the 3rd of May that it happened. Since I only started running the cron since the 11th of April, I have no idea if it's something that will happen once a month on the 3rd, or if it was a one time thing unrelated at all.

I looked around and didn't find anything related, so I though I'd just ask while I continued to tried to find out what happened. I currently changed the cron to make it run at 6am instead to see if I'd end up with the same thing again tomorrow.

```
 0 6 * * * /home/path/script.pl
```

**EDIT**

Everything was working fine, but then again on the 3rd of June, the same thing happened again. Could this be related to a cron problem or could it be something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was finally solved. There was a second cron being executed by root that was incorrectly written, which was making the script be called once a minute on the 3rd of the month instead of once a day at 3am.

The cron did not show up with the other cron jobs, and only by using the following command
did the cron job actually appear.

```
grep script /var/spool/cron/crontabs/*
```

I still don't understand but it's working correctly now.

Comment: It might be helpful to others if you showed the other cron job.

Comment: It was just like the one posted in the question but with 3 somewhere where it made it think it was the third of the month and not at 3am. I don't remember exactly, I deleted it as soon as I saw it.